# Python unable to locate mplstyle file in config folder

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add my custom.mplstyle to matplotlib. However,

```
mpl.get_configdir()
```

returns

```
/home/user/.config/matplotlib
```

In this folder I put the file

```
custom.mplstyle
```

However, when running Python I get

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.available
['Solarize_Light2', '_classic_test_patch', 'bmh', 'classic', 'dark_background',
 'fast', ..., 'seaborn-talk', 'seaborn-ticks', 'seaborn-white', 'tableau-lorblind10']
```

but not

```
'custom'
```

When running

```
plt.style.use('custom')
```

I get

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'custom'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are specifying a file, you need to give the whole path (absolute or relative) and name. E.g.

```
plt.style.use('../custom.mplstyle')
```

In the config folder it is in the stylelib subfolder. E.g.

```
/home/user/.config/matplotlib/stylelib
```

Comment: This does not work for me. It does work if I give the whole path. However, according to https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-creating-and-using-your-own-matplotlib-style-30de6c60bac0 it should not be necessary to provide the full file name.

Comment: Looking at the source, it appears that YOUR files need to go in `.config/matplotlib/stylelib`.  See if that leads to happiness.  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/style/core.py